# Spring Security antMatcher expression not works with path variable

Tags: java, regex, spring, spring-security, configuration

I need to provide certain **role** for accessing a URL in the following format:

```
/connector/{programId}/order/{anything here}
```

Where `programId` is an integer value so I'd tried the following and it doesn't work at all.

```java
.antMatchers('/connector/{programId:\\d+}/order/**').access("hasRole('CONNECTOR')")
```

But when I used `**` instead of the `programId` part it's working well. But how can I make it work with pathVariable (which is always an integer).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use `RegexRequestMatcher` instead of `AntPathRequestMatcher`.

```
.regexMatchers("/connector/(\\d+)/order/.*").access("hasRole('CONNECTOR')")
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using: 
`.regexMatchers("/connector/(\\d+)/order/.*").access("hasRole('CONNECTOR')")` 
But server response 405 error